# Adding user meta from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I need to add some data to the user's meta on my website. To do so, I use ajax to call a PHP file on my server, however, when the code is executed, it just returns null instead of the user class. Here is the JS code:

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/ajax/file.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},

    success: function (obj, textstatus) {
                      console.log(obj);
            }
});
</script>
```

And the contents of `file.php` are:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    global $current_user;
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // 3 llines above are just to display the error if any
    get_currentuserinfo();
    echo json_encode($current_user->ID);
?>
```

When I execute this, the error says that `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo() in...`

When I delete this line, the output is just `null`. I don't know If I'm doing everything correctly, but feel free to suggest different solutions. I do not need the ID to be returned, but the `$current_user` variable should not be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much of a reason to include a whole separate `.php` file to handle AJAX requests.

> **What's happening**: Because you're including your own custom `.php` file, it's being included *outside* of the WordPress environment, so you don't have access to WordPress variables and functions.

You have two options:

1. Use the built in [AJAX methods, actions, and handlers](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)
2. "Include" WordPress in your custom `.php` file

I'd recommend the first method. It's (almost) as simple as using the [`wp_ajax_{$action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/) hook, and posting the request to `admin-ajax.php` instead of your custom file.

Your JS would look something like this:

```
jQuery.post(
    ajax_object.ajax_url,
    {action: 'my_action'},
    function( response ){
        alert( 'Here is the response: ' + response );
    }
);
```

And then inside your `functions.php` (or similar) file, enqueue and localize the JS:

```
// Wherever you are enqueing this JS file, use `wp_localize_script` to pass variables to it
wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script', $link_to_your_js, array('jquery') );
wp_localize_script( 'your-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

and then still in your `functions.php` or similar file, handle the request:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_function' );
my_action_function(){
    $user_info = get_currentuserinfo();
    wp_send_json( $user_info );
}
```

Alternatively, using the second method, you can include `wp-load.php` into your `file.php`, using one of the [many answers on how to "include `wp-load.php`" in a file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26254/how-to-include-wp-load-php-from-any-location). This can cause some issues with scalability and maintenance though, so for something like this I'd *strongly* recommend the first method!

One last quick note: using `wp_localize_script` (like in the first method) you can actually pass the current user's information (or anything WordPress has access to, really) *directly* to the script, so you don't even need to make an AJAX request for it:

```
wp_localize_script( 'your-script', 'ajax_object', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'current_userinfo' => get_currentuserinfo()
);
```

Doing that will allow the `your-script` JS file to have access to `current_userinfo.ID` and all the other variables available to it directly!

Comment: Could you, please, clarify what is supposed to be written instead of ```'your-script'``` and  ```$link_to_your_js```. I am not too much of an expert in this topic, but I think I am supposed to write there a name of ```.js``` file, but what if it is embedded into HTML of the page?

Comment: If the script is just "embedded in the HTML" page, that's *wrong* as far as WordPress goes. Scripts should be [properly enqueued](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). I would recommend you do that, if possible. If not, the quick and dirty solution is to use #2 and just include `wp-load.php` in your `file.php` file, just know that in doing do you're really branching away from using WordPress as it's intended and may make future diagnostics and scaling more painful

Comment: Thank you, that works like a charm! I was just confused that ```'your script'``` can be an absolutely unassociated name. I ended up setting ```$link_to_your_js``` to ```content_url('ajax/get_meta.js')```.

Comment: Quick addition: what is the best way to pass an argument to php in this case? What I have done for now is just in js adding ```{action: 'my_action', arg: 'something'}``` and in php just writhing ```$arg = $_POST['arg']```. Works fine, not sure if there will be any consequences tho :)

Comment: The `your_script` part is entirely arbitrary - just a descriptive handle so you can reference/remove/add to that script later programatically! Re: Args: it depends. If it's not sensitive data, passing it like that is perfectly fine (and, arguably, what you should be doing). If it is sensitive or needs authorization/user permissions, making an AJAX request to return the data is generally the best - as anything passed to the script through localization is able to be changed